# Setting Size of Panel Does Not Update its Click Area WX

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have some code that looks like this:

```py
class Test():
  def __init__(self, parent_panel):
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    vbox = wx.Panel(parent_panel)
    vbox.SetSizer(sizer)

    self.panel = wx.Panel(vbox)
    sizer.Add(self.panel)
    self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.size)
    self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.click)

  def size(self, event):
    width = self.panel.GetSize().GetWidth()
    self.panel.SetSize((width, width))

  def click(self, event):
    print("Click received!")
```

The default size for the panel is something like (50, 200). So when I resize it to (200, 200), I expect the whole panel to change size. The click event is only received when I click on the original part of the panel. Is there any way to make the whole panel receive the click event?

The panel is also being used with EVT_PAINT, and I had to call `dc.DestroyClippingRegion()` before it would draw over the whole panel. In the inspector, the outline always surrounded the whole panel, even before calling `dc.DestroyClippingRegion()`.

Comment: @NeilMacneae, you didn't provide the full code. Where is the panel created? Does it have any children? Can you show the full code, please.

Comment: @Igor, I tried to keep it simple, as the original code is way to large to put here. See edits.

Comment: `self.panel = wx.Panel(vbox)` does not look right

Comment: It's very strange to set the panel size from its own `EVT_SIZE` handler. What exactly are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: @NeilMacneale, is this panel the only child of `parent_parent`? Why you are not using wx.EXPAND flag when you adding it to the sizer?

Comment: Some comments. **a)** `self.panel` is a child of `vbox`, but you only handle size-events for the child. **b)** Setting a panel as child of another panel is allowed, but rare. I'd use this set only for different backgrounds colors. **c)** Remember that the user can resize a frame, but not a panel

Comment: @Ripi2 I have multiple elements as children of the vbox. I was trying to organize them like you would with nested <div>s in html. Is there a better way to this?

Comment: @macroland why doesn't that look right? Can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. I was using nested panels before, as my previous UI design was mostly in HTML. After setting up a GridBagSizer, this works as expected. I was avoiding this before, as none of the elements were expanding when I expected them to. `sizer.AddGrowableRow()` did the trick.